# NodeJS setTimeout looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want to run this function every N seconds (5 seconds now but that can change) with a `setTimeout`, but it keeps looping after the first run, I tried everything, but still nothing :/

Thanks!

Where setTimeout is:

```js
if (data.status != "TELEMETRY") {
  switch (data.status) {
    case "POSSIBLE COLLISION":
      console.log("The game has detected a POSSIBLE COLLISION!\n");
      break;
    case "JOB STARTED":
      console.log("A JOB has been started!\n");
      break;
    case "JOB PAUSED":
      console.log("A started JOB has been PAUSED!\n");
      break;
    case "JOB UNPAUSED":
      console.log("A paused JOB has been UNPAUSED!\n");
      break;
    case "JOB CONTINUE":
      console.log("A JOB has been RESUMED from last session!\n");
      break;
  }
  sendJobData(data, jobLogger);
} else {
  if (data.jobData.onJob == true) {
    if (data.jobData.status == 1) {
      console.log("The user is doing a JOB!")
    } else if (data.jobData.status == 2) {
      console.log("The user has completed a JOB!");
    } else if (data.jobData.status == 3) {
      console.log("The user has cancelled a JOB!");
    } else {
      console.log(data.jobData.status);
      console.log("Unknown value!");
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      sendJobData(data, jobLogger);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

My setTimeout:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  sendJobData(data, jobLogger);
}, 5000);
```

Function code:

```js
function sendJobData(data, jobLogger) {
  var trackerData = {}
  var steamKey = 'SteamID';
  trackerData[steamKey] = [];

  var trackerJobData = {
    Data: data
  };

  trackerData[steamKey].push(trackerJobData);

  var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'steamid': data.telemetry.user.steamID,
    'jobdata': JSON.stringify(trackerJobData)
  });

  var options = {
    hostname: //url,
      port: 443,
    path: '/file.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
  };

  var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
  jobLogger.jobLog("############ BEGIN JOB DATA LOG #############\n");
  jobLogger.jobLog(postData + "\n");
  jobLogger.jobLog("############ END JOB DATA LOG #############\n");
  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
}
```

Comment: please upload the code where the `setTimeout` in

Comment: Nope... Can't see why that happens from your code. but consider using the [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) method

Comment: You know about `setInterval`?

Comment: @Eldshe Still same result